# meteor dynamic schema usage

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-collection2, simple-schema

I plan to build a dynamic schema and create an autoform from that schema. In the template where the form will be displayed I plan on doing this in

```
template.formPage.onCreated(function(){//do stuff});
```

What I am curious about though is getting the form onto the page:

Can I just use the usual AutoForm helper to generate the form directly in the template ie quickForm or would I need to create a new template helper to pass details from the newly created schema to the template?

Bit confused about what's supposed to happen where.

To be more concise: the user can create a document called exercise for example: this would have a name field, a description field etc and they could also decide what the measurable units are, these are stored as sub documents, each sub document has 3 fields: name, value, unit. I created a schema and sub schema and this works fine.

The issue is that when a user is doing a workout they should be able to select an exercise from the collection of exercises (all of which are created by the admin) and from that data create a form (read schema) to upload a document to the workout collection.

The measurable values in the exercise document will describe what form fields are required in the workout form depending on what exercise is being performed.

Essentially the exercise collection is a collection of schemas.

Comment: first things first: why dynamic schema? You can define objects and sub-objects, arrays etc... so there must be a viable description of your schema that may be static. The point of a schema is to give a reference to go by to do validation etc... a 'dynamic' schema is kind of an oxymoron.

Comment: second, you will need the schema to also be on the server side to submit your form and validate... so now you have a problem: how do you validate the schema that is meant to validate the form if it is not already (statically) on the server, and you can't trust the client to submit a valid schema?

Comment: The reason I think I need it is that I want users to be able to define their own exercise document with a sub document array of measurable values with a name, a value and  a unit. This document will then be used as a template for the exercise and a schema and form will be built from it when the user wants to enter a workout into a workout collection.

Comment: The server side was something I thought about as well but I could write the code as a class and then call it in the method that processes the form data as well as on the client for the form generation I saw that there are quite a few hooks in autoform and collection2 to enable you to perform actions in various stages of the form processing.

Comment: better to define things as 'property','value' to define custom fields: you are confusing the schema with the data.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I am using property value pairs but the document also contains a varying number of property value pairs defined by the user in a previous process.

Comment: I mean the schema is a representation of the data, the data is what varies. Can you show variations of what your data looks like?

Comment: I edited the original description to better describe what I am trying to do.

Comment: when you search through a database, you search by field. if there are no field the same, it's not searchable, not indexable etc... you get the idea.
So in your case if your Exercise DB is a DB of schema, and you say you have schemas defined as doc and sub doc, then your Exercise DB objects are like you say: {name, description, sub-docs: [{name, value, unit}, {name,value,unit}]}